# mod_python ignoring shebang and using Python 2 instead of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-python

I'm trying to run a script in the browser. I installed [`mod_python`](http://modpython.org/) for running web-based applications on the server and set a shebang in my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import sys

def index():
    print ("Content-type: text/html\n")
    print('Version Python {0}'.format(sys.version_info[0]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    index()
```

However, when I run my script from the browser ([my application](http://myautobest.ru/check-robots/index.py)), I see that the Python version is 2. When I run the script from the console, using:

```
python3 index.py
```

Python version 3.3.5 is used as expected. Why is `mod_python` ignoring the shebang?

**UPD. The Question closed**

- I opted out of the mod_python.
- I founded a mistake in shebang (I should set \n line endings for Unix).
- Writed wrapper on php for running python 3

Comment: Can you show the starting few lines of the entire code? And are you running this in linux?

Comment: @AnandSKumar i add entire script in my question, i use CentOS

Comment: @jonrsharpe if i run script <code>./myscriptname.py</code> raise error <code>No such file or directory</code>

Comment: @jonrsharpe i send request to server from my browser. [My script](http://myautobest.ru/check-robots/index.py)

Comment: I think OP wants to embed python3 code in html and run it.

Comment: @kmario23 My application writed on python. And now I created API for them. Therefore i configure a server for run python not only from console

Comment: This is an issue with how mod_python was installed. See http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/installation.html#running-configure for instructions if you installed mod_python yourself. If you had a package manager install it you'll need to look at their documentation. I'm voting to close and move this to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

Set executable flag on the file:

```
chmod a+x yourfile.py
```

Then, execute it as:

```
./yourfile.py
```

Comment: Although correct in the general sense, I'm not sure this helps the OP with whatever they mean by *"from browser"*.

Comment: @LeoKomarov then *provide enough information*, otherwise you'll never get an answer

Answer (score 0):

When shebang is used follow this steps to run the code.

This makes your file executable

```
chmod +x index.py
```

This helps your code to execute

```
./index.py
```